# passing user input as parameter to src in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-api, google-custom-search

I have a form field in HTML where I want to collect the user's input, store it in a variable, and pass to a src tag that invokes the Google Custom Search API. Is there a way to do this working only on the front-end?

Form:

```
<body>
  <form id="InputForm" method="post" >
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Input Form</legend>
      <div>
        <label for="Task">To do...</label>
        <input type="text" id="Task" value="" style="width: 600px;" />
      </div>
      <div class="submitLabel" style="margin-left: 425px;">
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
```

And src tag:

```
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MYKEY&amp;cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&amp;q=VARIABLEHERE&amp;callback=hndlr">
```

I tried to store the user input in a variable by using getElementByID, but have had no success with trying to insert the variable in the src attribute.

```
    var param = document.getElementById("Task").value;
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MYKEY&amp;cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&amp;q='+param+'&amp;callback=hndlr"
    document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].parentNode.appendChild(script);
```

The hndlr function formats and displays the results returned by the API. It works when I use a predefined q parameter.

Comment: `I tried to store the user input in a variable by using getElementByID, but have had no success with trying to insert the variable in the src attribute.` - Please share this code so we can see why it might not work. See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details.

Comment: Code added. This was adapted from a solution to another question that I found, but I'm very new to front-end languages so I'm not really sure that HTML DOM works in conjunction with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the variable with the data you want then it is very easy to insert it into the src attribute of a script tag.

You could use jquery to create a new script tag with your custom src attribute:

```
var myData = "ThisDataHere";
$('<script>').attr({
    src: 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MYKEY&amp;cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&amp;q='+myData+'&amp;callback=hndlr',
    type: 'text/javascript'}).appendTo('body')
```